# How to implement a toolbar button with drop down menu?

Tags: macos, cocoa

The following picture is a screenshot of part of Mail app’s toolbar. The flag button is apparently an NSSegmentedCell button with a drop down menu. I want the button to have a standard action when clicked on the icon part, and a menu to drop down when the chevron is clicked. Is there a standard way to do it? I used a 2 segment NSSegmentedButton that achieves most of what I want, but I can’t get the chevron icon to show when I assign a menu to the second segment.

Edit: I could make it work if there was a system template for that chevron. Is there any other way to get it other than drawing it myself?

[image]

Comment: This might provide some ideas... https://youtu.be/Qr6EX-JIZZU Basically the icon is the first menu item, which itself is hidden.

Comment: Thanks, but it’s not really what I want. It doesn’t give the same result.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this, but my first approach would be to install a segmented cell with two buttons, a "flag" and a "down chevron"; the flag action does whatever you want it to do and the "down chevron" button's action invokes `-[NSMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:]` (Oh snap, I actually have an interface that does almost exactly that, a segmented control with + and - buttons, where the + button pops up a menu with a choice of items to add.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out NSSegmentedControl provides `setShowsMenuIndicator` that draws the down chevron for a segment just like an NSPopupButton. Unfortunately, it’s only available from macOS 10.13 onwards.