# Drop-down menu in NSToolbar like Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nspopupbutton, nstoolbar

I'd like a toolbar button with an attached dropdown menu, like the "Flag" button in the toolbar in Mail.app:

[image: Flag menu from Mail.app]

I'd hoped that making a normal `NSMenuItem` and adding a menu as the `menuFormRepresentation` would do the trick, but that menu only appears when the button goes into overflow mode.

I had also hoped that adding an `NSPopupButton` as a custom view would work, but that makes the whole view a menu, whereas I want the left part of the component to behave like a normal button, and the right dropdown part bring up the menu.

Is there some trick to making the NSToolbarItem show a component like this, or is this two custom views stuck together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a toolbar button with drop down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971844/how-to-implement-a-toolbar-button-with-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing magical about `NSToolbar` here. That's just one of the ways you can set up `NSSegmentedControl`, regardless of whether it appears as a toolbar item's custom view or on its own.

You can't set this up in Interface Builder (storyboard), but [`NSSegmentedControl`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssegmentedcontrol) has APIs for assigning menus to segments:

```
segmentControl.setMenu(myMenu, forSegment: 1)
segmentControl.setShowsMenuIndicator(true, forSegment: 1) // for the little arrow
```

You probably want to set the tracking mode to [`momentary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssegmentedcontrol.switchtracking/1535340-momentary), since your segment control is acting as a set of visually-connected buttons, not a choose-one-of-N selector.

When the user clicks either segment, your action method will need to use the `selectedSegment` to decide whether to perform the action associated with the "button" side or ignore the click (letting the menu show for the other side).

Comment: NSToolbar does sometimes do magical things to embedded controls (e.g., NSSearchField renders differently in a toolbar than outside), so I was hoping that there was some way to trigger this magic for an NSButton. But your solution doesn't seem too onerous; a quick prototype is looking pretty good. Thanks!