# How to implement a NSButton like the Finder button

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

Please refer to the screenshot, I want to implement a NSButton like the buttons on Finder window. It seems that the button style is similar with a NSButton **recessed**. I have tried the recessed button but it is a little different from the Finder button, even the one which have a drop down menu. I have no idea how to make a drop down menu with recessed button.

If I choose to make a bevel style borderless NSButton with a special image, I cannot set a highlighted hover background whose size is larger than the image inside. The hover area is always the same with the image.

So any body known how to implement this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a toolbar button with drop down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971844/how-to-implement-a-toolbar-button-with-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMenuToolbarItem` instead and check the inline comment in the sample source:

---

Assign this custom class `MainWindowController` to the initial `NSWindowController` controller:

```swift
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    
    // `NSMenuToolbarItem` Items
    var dropDownMenu: NSMenu = {
        var menu = NSMenu(title: "DropDown")
        let item1 = NSMenuItem(title: "Item 1", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        let item2 = NSMenuItem(title: "Item 1", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        let item3 = NSMenuItem(title: "Item 3", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        menu.items = [item1, item2, item3]
        return menu
    }()
    
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        
        configureToolbar()
    }
    
    private func configureToolbar() {
        if  let safeWindow = self.window {
            let toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: "mainWindowToolbar")
            toolbar.delegate = self
            toolbar.displayMode = .default
            
            safeWindow.toolbarStyle = .automatic
            
            safeWindow.toolbar = toolbar
            safeWindow.toolbar?.validateVisibleItems()
        }
    }
}

extension MainWindowController: NSToolbarDelegate {
    func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar, itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem? {
       
        let toolbarItem = NSMenuToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
        toolbarItem.showsIndicator = true // To display DropDown Indicator
        toolbarItem.menu = self.dropDownMenu
        toolbarItem.isBordered = true // Show ToolBar Item Background on Mouse Hover
        toolbarItem.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "ellipsis.circle", accessibilityDescription: "")
        return toolbarItem
    }
    
    func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [NSToolbarItem.Identifier("DropDownAction")]
    }
    
    func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [NSToolbarItem.Identifier("DropDownAction")]
    }
}
```

---

**Output**:

[image]